# How to load and use functions from a js script?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am loading an external js file on aReact Next js page.
How to access the function (`FooInit`) of `init.js`?

```
export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    FooInit() // how to access FooInit?
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <Script beforeInteractive src="https://foo.boo/js/init.js"
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the `FooInit` function from the external JavaScript file in your React Next.js component, you can follow these steps:

- Make sure the external script has loaded before calling the function.
  You can use the `onLoad` event handler of the `Script` component.
- Access the `FooInit` function from the `window` object since it's a global
  function.

Here's an example implementation:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Script from 'next/script';

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.FooInit) {
      window.FooInit();
    }
  }, []);

  const handleScriptLoad = () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.FooInit) {
      window.FooInit();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Script
        beforeInteractive
        src="https://foo.boo/js/init.js"
        onLoad={handleScriptLoad}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

In this example, the `handleScriptLoad` function will be called once the external script has loaded. Inside this function, we check if the `FooInit` function is available in the window object and call it if it exists. We also do the same check and call in the `useEffect` hook for cases when the script is already loaded and cached by the browser.

By following these steps, you can successfully access and call the `FooInit` function from the external JavaScript file within your Next.js React component.